# Function in angular doesn't use this parameter

Tags: html, angular, typescript, function, google-maps

I'm working with API Geocode of Google, and the function works fine until I need to use this.singleGeocode and this.resultsMarker. This is my component code:

```
interface Location {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}
singleGeocode: Location;
resultsMarkers: Location[];


 addressToCoordinates(addressToSearch: string) {
      this.geoCoder.geocode({ address: addressToSearch }, function ( results, status) {
  debugger;
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    let p = results[0].geometry.location;
    debugger;
    this.singleGeocode.lat = p.lat();
    this.singleGeocode.lng = p.lng();
    this.resultsMarkers.push(this.singleGeocode);
  }
 });
}
```

That's my HTML code:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="startingLat" [longitude]="startingLng" [zoom]="startingZoom" (zoomChange)="onZoomChange($event)">
<div *ngIf="selectedZoom > 4">
  <agm-marker-cluster imagePath="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/images/m" [minimumClusterSize]="2">
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of resultsMarkers; let i = index"
                (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)"
                [latitude]="m.lat"
                [longitude]="m.lng"
                [label]="test"
                [markerDraggable]="false">
    </agm-marker>
  </agm-marker-cluster>
</agm-map>
```

How can make the function read my this parameters, so my HTML will use it? Or how I can change my code to make it work?

EDIT:
I tried to put the bind, but those parameters are still undefined.

```
this.geoCoder.geocode({ address: addressToSearch }, function (results, status) {
  debugger;
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  let p = results[0].geometry.location;
  debugger;
  this.singleGeocode.lat = p.lat();
  this.singleGeocode.lng = p.lng();
  this.resultsMarkers.push(this.singleGeocode);
  }
}.bind(this));
}
```

Also, I tried with => but still undefined:

```
this.geoCoder.geocode({ address: addressToSearch }, (results, status) => {
  debugger;
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  let p = results[0].geometry.location;
  debugger;
  this.singleGeocode.lat = p.lat();
  this.singleGeocode.lng = p.lng();
  this.resultsMarkers.push(this.singleGeocode);
  }
});
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Conver this into arrow function `function ( results, status) {` to `(results,status)=> {`

Comment: what library comes from `geoCoder`?

Comment: this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your Maps setup.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry but I'm newbie in angular

Comment: Well, what I say is not related to angular, it is related to geocode API configuration. [Document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you initializing `singleGeocode` and `resultsMarkers` before you assign them values? If not then this is likely the problem. See if it helps modifying your code as below:

```
  interface Location {
      lat: number;
      lng: number;
  }

  // class starts here

  singleGeocode: Location;
  resultsMarkers: Location[] = []; // new

  addressToCoordinates(addressToSearch: string) {
    this.geoCoder.geocode({ address: addressToSearch }, function(
      results,
      status
    ) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        let p = results[0].geometry.location;
        // new
        this.singleGeocode = {
          lat: p.lat(),
          lng: p.lng()
        };
        this.resultsMarkers.push(this.singleGeocode);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Nice! Happy to help :)